# Extending the "compound" class name

Tags: css, less

I expect that this LESS

```
.layout {
  &__sidebar {
    color: red;
  }
}

.layout__sidebar {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.foo {
  &:extend(.layout__sidebar);
}
```

would end up the `.foo` class to have both the `color` and `background-color` properties to be inherited, but instead that's how it's compiled:

```
.layout__sidebar {
  color: red;
}
.layout__sidebar,
.foo {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Is it a bug in LESS or am I mis-using it somehow?

Online demo: http://codepen.io/zerkms/pen/vGJvBV

Apparently this is a bug, but as soon as I just posted a bug there is no confirmation for that yet: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2857

Comment: Yeah I'm going to hazard that it's a bug based on the documentation you refer to.

Comment: @Harry definitely a duplicate, thanks